# inlineformset_factory choices not set correctly when using django-schemas

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created an inlineformset_factory, but when I implement the Post method on my view the system mentioned that my inline form is not valid.

After some debugging I found out that the choices that are in one of my inlineformset_factory fields are not accurate, this happens because I'm using django-schemas.
for some reason when the inlineformset_factory is defined, it uses the public schemas and not the tenant schema, which makes the choices in my inlineformset_factory field incorrect.

**Note:** The model that uses the inlineformset_factory has 2 Foreign Key 1 with the Configuration Object and the other with User, the issue occurs with the User.

Here is the code that I have

**model.py**

```
class Configuration(Control):
    uuid = kp.ObjectIDField()
    name = kp.ObjectNameField()
    description = kp.ObjectDescriptionField()

class ConfigurationMember(models.Model):
    uuid = kp.ObjectIDField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    configuration = models.ForeignKey(Configuration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
 MemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Configuration, ConfigurationMember,
                                  fk_name='forecastConfiguration',
                                  fields=['user', 'owner'], can_delete=False, extra=3)
```

**View.py**

```
class ConfigurationCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Configuration
    form_class = ConfigurationCreateForm
    template_name = 'frontend/base/config_create.html'
    object = None
    # success_url = ''

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles GET requests and instantiates blank versions of the form
        and its inline formsets.
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        member_formset = MemberFormSet()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'member_formset': member_formset})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance and its inline
        formsets with the passed POST variables and then checking them for
        validity.
        """
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        member_formset = MemberFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and member_formset.is_valid():
            self.form_valid(form, member_formset)
            messages.add_message( self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Configurations has been saved')
            return redirect(reverse('config_detail', kwargs={'uuid': self.object.uuid}))
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, 'Error when creating the Configuration')
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'member_formset': member_formset})
```

**Note:** I noticed while debuging that every time i bounce the server, the first thing it does is call the inlineformset_factory definition, at that time the system doent have a schema defined, because of this it uses the PUBLIC schema, however, in my view, the inlineformset_factory is created the system instead of creating a new inlineformset instance it uses the one available in the factory which has been instaciated incorrectly.

If im using scehmas how to i create a factory specific to the schema and not the complete application?

Comment: I recently added an `inlineformset_factory` to tenant specific schemas and do not have this issue. Have you tried moving the app/models which have this issue from the `SHARED_APPS` into the `TENANT_APPS` so that these apps are tenant only?